# Python Задачи 9 класс

Tags: python, циклы

Я только начал изучать *Python* и очень плохо понимаю как что работает. Объясните пожалуйста, что неправильно. Вот задача и мой код:

Напишите программу, которая в последовательности натуральных чисел определяет сумму чисел, кратных 3 и оканчивающихся на 4. Программа получает на вход количество чисел в последовательности, а затем сами числа. В последовательности всегда имеется число, кратное 3 и оканчивающееся на 4.
Количество чисел не превышает 100. Введённые числа по модулю не превышают 300.
Программа должна вывести одно число: сумму чисел, кратных 3 и оканчивающихся на 4.
Пример работы программы:

Входные данные: `3 24 25 54`    
Выходные данные: `78`

```
b=int(input())
numbers=300
for i in range(b):
    a=int(input())
    if (a) % 3== 0 and a %10 ==4:
        a=a
print(a)
```

Буду признателен если поможете, а за одно не могли бы посоветовать с чего начать такому дереву как я ? 
Что смотреть/читать/решать?

Comment: Что это такое `a=a`? О_О

Comment: Что читать: циклы, списки, срезы. Условные операторы, операции присваения и сравнения

Comment: Когда приведете в чувство свою программу, вычислите `-4 %10`. Будет сюрприз.

Answer (score 2):

`numbers = через split()` используя разделитель по умолчанию `' '` мы разбиваем строку с числами на список. Через map итерируем полученный список и вызываем для каждого его элемента функцию int. На выходе получаем список чисел.

```
def sum_of_numbers(n, numbers):
    my_sum = 0
    for number in numbers: # итерируем список
        if number % 3 == 0 and number % 10 == 4:
            my_sum += number # складываем подходящие под условия цифры
    return my_sum

n = int(input("Количество чисел в последовательности: "))
numbers = list(map(int, input("Сами числа через пробел: ").split()))

result = sum_of_numbers(n, numbers)
print("Сумму чисел, кратных 3 и оканчивающихся на 4:", result)
```

А так в целом вектор мысли был верным.

```
Количество чисел в последовательности: 4
Сами числа через пробел: 3 24 25 54
Сумму чисел, кратных 3 и оканчивающихся на 4: 78

[Program finished]
```

Лично я в вас верю, но общественность намекает что пример нужно упростить. Давайте исправим пару недочетов в вашей программе:

```
b=int(input())
my_sum=0 # нам нужна пустая переменная, что бы записывать в нее сумму всех подходящих чисел
for i in range(b):
    a=int(input())
    if a % 3== 0 and a %10 ==4:
        my_sum+=a # можно явно указать my_sum=my_sum+a
print(my_sum)

4
3
24
25
54
78

[Program finished]
```

Из пожеланий: давайте переменным осмысленные названия.

Comment: думаю для 9 класса это слишком сложная программа.

Comment: @Nymos если человек допер до такой конструкции if num % 3 == 0 and num % 10 == 4: то я с вами не согласен что тут что-то сложное осталось‍♀️

Comment: Школьник пишет: `Я только начал изучать Python и очень плохо понимаю как что работает. `, возможно, он даже не знает пока, как создавать функции в python, а ты его так нагружаешь, как же шалун

Comment: Конечно, ты прав, что в будущем стоит всегда писать код в функциях, однако сейчас это не является для него приоритетом. Для него главное - **решить задачу ОГЭ**. Поэтому стоит подходить к этому более гибко, не заставляя его писать лишний код. ты ему дал, будто он индус и ему платят за количество строчек в программе. Ты пока не можешь это осознать, но в будущем, когда будешь преподавать (если, конечно, захочешь), поймешь мою точку зрения.

Comment: Вы же видите, что `sum` у вас в коде подсвечивается красным, как и другие ключевые слова питона? Не используйте встроенную функцию `sum` в качестве названия своей переменной, это плохой стиль.

Comment: @CrazyElf оу, спасибо за замечание;)

Comment: `используя разделитель по умолчанию ' '` - ну вообще нет, по умолчанию `split()` разбивает по любым пробельным символам, хоть пробелам, хоть табам, хоть переносам строк, причем группируя эти символы (группа идущих подряд пробельных символов считается одним разделителем).